# Generics in TypeScript what makes them useful

Tags: javascript, node.js, generics, typescript, typescript2.0

I was reading this article from Eric Elliot:

“You Might Not Need TypeScript (or Static Types)” @_ericelliott https://medium.com/javascript-scene/you-might-not-need-typescript-or-static-types-aa7cb670a77b

He talks about this TS function

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```

What is the `<T>` syntax for? I believe it's for generics but I don't really understand the purpose.

Why doesn't the fact that `arg` is declared as type `T` take care of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the  syntax for? I believe it's for generics but I don't really understand the purpose.

It is indeed for generics. The purpose of generics is to ensure a constratint between values.

In the identity function the constraint enforced is that the value returned from the function *is of the same type* as was passed in as the argument.

More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this explains it pretty well!

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

It seems the `<T>` is necessary to declare a variable type. However I don't this is a great practice. Probably better to define an interace instead of a completely generic type variable.